# Unable to pass data from jade to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am learning jade and following is my code snippet

```
extends layout


block content
  h1= title
  p Token is #{token.access_token}
      script(type='text/javascript')
          var tokenValue = JSON.parse(token);
          sayhi(tokenValue);
```

Inside my test.js I have

```
function sayhi(token) {
    console.log(token);
}
```

If I send a text from sayhi - it works perfectly but if i send tokenValue - I get following error:

```
unexpected text ;

   at Object.Lexer.fail (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:872:11)
   at Object.Lexer.next (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:931:15)
   at Object.Lexer.lookahead (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/lexer.js:113:46)
   at Parser.lookahead (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:102:23)
   at Parser.peek (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:79:17)
   at Parser.tag (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:751:22)
   at Parser.parseTag (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:737:17)
   at Parser.parseExpr (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:211:21)
   at Parser.block (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:707:25)
   at Parser.tag (/home/shardul/WebstormProjects/trial/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:816:24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues that i see here.

1. You need to define the script as a text block, using a period.
2. `token` is currently a variable in Jade that needs to be encoded for JS, not decoded.
3. You'll need to interlope `token` to the text block.

Final code:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Token is #{token.access_token}
      script(type='text/javascript').
          var tokenValue = #{JSON.stringify(token)};
          sayhi(tokenValue);
```